# React Native an image is not displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I keep the data from the API in the state. Then I change the image in URI property accordingly. But the image cannot be displayed. If I reinstall the app, the picture comes. I placed a text tag on the page to Test it and gave it the same status. Works correctly for text. But he doesn't work for Image.

fetch API part:

```
 const { data } = await profileStore(bodyFormData);
        if (data) {
          await setPath(data.photo);
        }
```

View part:

```
 <View>
          {
            path &&
              <Image
                style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50}}
                source={{ uri: 'http://192.168.1.106:80/'+path}}
              />
            }
  </View>
```

Comment: Please copy & paste the code in the question, code shouldn't be in a screenshot or an image.

Comment: Thank yo Sinan. thank you for the warning. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `source = {{uri: "path"}}` to `source={{require("path")}}`. Your app needs to import the image from the path

Comment: Maybe the path is the issue. TMaybe try a different path, for test purposes following [this link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image). If that doesn't work, I don't know what is the solution unfortunately

Comment: Sinan, path is absolutely right. Also I have tried. as I said, I printed a path to the text component to test and it works correctly. But for some reason, the image does not reprocess itself.

Comment: Unexpected behavior, hope you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

try using `http://192.168.1.106:80/${path}`
try declare it on top and using it as variable,
lastly do check your path

Comment: I've tried this before. it didn't work :(